# NSTableBackgroundView

Tags: macos, exception, scroll, nstableview

I have a `ViewController` which has a single `TableView` within its content.
Within the ViewController I access the actual Table via:

```
NSView * myView = self.view.subviews[0];
myView = myView.subviews[0];
NSTableView *myTable = myView.subviews[0];
[self.targets sortUsingDescriptors: [myTable sortDescriptors]];
[myTable reloadData];
```

This actually is clumsy but seems to work.  Except that when I mouse down within the table when the vertical scroll bars are active. Then, I raise an exception because in the final line of accessing `subviews` to reach `myTable`, the `subview` array has several `NSTableBackgroundViews` before the actual `TableView` that I created and want to access.

`NSTableBackgroundView` apparently is not documented and does not have a `sortDescriptors` method (hence the exception).

Perhaps someone can point out a better way to get to the table which is more reliable, or can someone say whether enumerating the final `subview` array to find the desired `ClassOf NSTableView` is safe?

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

in lieu of any other answers, I implemented planB, I took the array of subviews and enumerated on them to find the actual NSTableView. This seems to work when I bang on the UI to test it and no more flags are raised.

I wish there were a cleaner way I could discover to get the view I want without traversing all the subviews.